# How to connect an Apple App to an external device e.g. temperature sensor?

Tags: android, ios, hardware

My company wants to develop an Apple or Android app to tackle with an external sensor device, lets say the temperature of milk via a temperature sensor. The external device is tbd and currently under investigation, could be using a connector or WIFI or Bluetooth.
Do we need to apply for Apple MFI program to get access to the protocols used for that?
Since we do not want to implement the external device, i guessMFI license is not needed. But where do we get ressources to learn how to connect?

Answer (score 2):

For Android you could do this using an **Arduino Module**

You can do this using Bluetooth / WiFi  as your need!

Then make an Android  app  and communicate with the **Arduino Module** to get your data via **Bluetooth / WiFi**

For  **Ios/Apple**

A  Plus side of using   **Arduino**

You can use   **Arduino**  for **Iphone As Well as For Android**

How?  here you go ---->  **http://www.raywenderlich.com/38841/arduino-tutorial-temperature-sensor**

If you really need to Know the temperature of milk via a temperature sensor  here is a Full Tutorial
Which uses a Temperature sensor to  find the  Temperature and Query it to your **Iphone**

1 All the Requirements are given.

2 Cost Of all the parts with links

3 Source Code is also provided

4 Working

5 Circuit Diagrams

6 Step by Step Guide to code

7.Libraries are provided

8 Everything needed is provided for free (Software part)

Know everything About **Arduino**  http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arduino.cc%2F&ei=K344UpiFCo2yrgfXi4CACQ&usg=AFQjCNENSvy_VhDmp9YsE0x0X702I5teeQ&sig2=utVrSYYIMBFAFStVGq--RQ&bvm=bv.52164340,d.dGI

Tutorials :-

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CFEQtwIwBA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DkS5C5Xhsv24&ei=g3w4UrDcLsOQkQWA44DQAQ&usg=AFQjCNHED0FWP8FpK29uEnUzxDeyh6751g&sig2=2rfcYp4Zqx5dt-KVri5sfw&bvm=bv.52164340,d.dGI

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CFgQtwIwBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DY9R5O0mbvME&ei=g3w4UrDcLsOQkQWA44DQAQ&usg=AFQjCNHSbk25-B0KJTejgr4QewfK5aNivw&sig2=YZCyYJb_AVmvgmXVoAWLLw&bvm=bv.52164340,d.dGI

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.arduino.cc%2F2013%2F07%2F09%2Flet-your-arduino-talk-to-your-android-phone-without-any-android-programming%2F&ei=g3w4UrDcLsOQkQWA44DQAQ&usg=AFQjCNHRdHAkS8MBau7hN3Bv5HtN-fvU0A&sig2=lboevloczOpc28XwVM9cmQ&bvm=bv.52164340,d.dGI

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.arduino.cc%2Findex.php%3Ftopic%3D168329.0&ei=g3w4UrDcLsOQkQWA44DQAQ&usg=AFQjCNGQE5LOB60XfXmuiJdNYbIxqAqgJw&sig2=yk3dGNYeUOitvr6a4S8DkQ&bvm=bv.52164340,d.dGI

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand a little more on Metalhead's answer. If you go the Arduino route, you will need to buy an Ethernet Shield or a Wifi Shield to use Ethernet or WiFi respectively. You can use Bluetooth if you are close enough to the sensor; you will still need to buy a Shield

One advantage of using the Wifi or Ethernet Shields is that you can use MQTT to remotely monitor your sensors over the Internet.

You can also look into a Raspberry Pi. It has more processing power than the Arduino and it comes with a built-in Ethernet card. If you are a Java programmer, you can install Java in a Raspberry Pi; you can't in an Arduino.

Android also gives you the option of using [Android Open Accessory](http://source.android.com/accessories/index.html) if you want to communicate and control the Arduino using USB or Bluetooth. You will have to be connected to the board directly via a USB cable (if using USB to communicate) since it needs the 5V from your phone to operate.

Comment: It's worth adding here that hobbyist and evaluation boards are great for evaluation and prototyping, but are not generally suitable as components of commercial products - you'd typically use the as the basis for your own hardware developments.